# How can i select same name Radio button with java script In android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, radio-button

I have multiple radio button with same name and id and want to select the radio button with javascript.

```
<input type="radio" name="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX" id="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX" value="1" class="middle"> 

<input type="radio" name="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX" id="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX" value="2" class="middle"> 

<input type="radio" name="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX" id="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX" value="3" class="middle">
```

I am trying with below code but that is not working

```
(function() { document.getElementById('Custom.SELECTED_INDEX')[2].checked =  true; return 'success'; })();
```

Any suggestion or recommendation is welcome

Comment: you can only have one element with each ID. `document.getElementById(...)` returns only a single element, so your attempt to index the result will result in an error.

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond for your reply . i have multiple radio button with same id and i am using index but that is not working

Comment: I knew that, and explained why it doesn't work. You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID, it's not valid HTML and *will* cause issues like this. Fix your HTML.

Comment: pls tell me where i ma doing wrong document.getElementById('Custom.SELECTED_INDEX')[2].checked = true;

Comment: i can not edit HTML . That is third party website and website is working fine but i am not able to handle that from Android

Comment: well ok, that's strange, but it might not matter - you just need another way of selecting the elements. `getElementsByName` should work here.

Comment: @RobinZigmond you are right in stating that having several tags with the same id renders the HTML invalid. FYI though, you can actually select several items by id with a property selector: document.querySelectorAll("[id=document.querySelectorAll('input[name="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX"]')]"). See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/spzb3ur5/

Comment: @RobinZigmond however, we should select the tags by name (as suggested in my answer, with code) and the op should ensure that the HTML is valid, if possible.

Comment: @LajosArpad agreed, selecting by name is exactly what I suggested a few comments up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just write a proper selector, query for it and use it as you wish:

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="Custom.SELECTED_INDEX"]');
```